# Using conditionalPanel to create a temporary banner that disappears if user navigates away

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create a welcome message for when a user first opens the shiny webpage. Currently I have it such that it is constantly on the first tabPanel. Is there a way to make it disappear when the user navigates away and then back to that panel?

```
fluidRow(
  column(width=12,
         tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",  id = "tabs1", 
                     tabPanel("Express Usage", wellPanel("Welcome! Please select the libraries you are interested in viewing from below and use the tabs to navigate between graphs. It is best to limit your selection to no more than 5 libraries at a time"), plotOutput("express_Plot", height=400)),
                     tabPanel("Juvenile Usage", plotOutput("juvenile_Plot", height=400)), 
                     tabPanel("test", h3(textOutput("text_test")))))
  ),
```